# Datepickers Bootstrap - No cargar fechas automáticamente

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap, datepicker

Buen día.

Tengo 3 datepickers (campos de fecha) en mi proyecto, fecha de inicio, de fin y una de vigencia ..

Al ingresar la primer fecha, automáticamente se carga la fecha actual en los otros dos campos, sin embargo la fecha de vigencia no es obligatoria .. por lo que no quiero que cargue nada. Cómo puedo hacer que no se carguen fechas automáticamente en los campos??

Este es el código.. y es igual para los tres campos, solo cambio el id de cada input: --> código completo del jsp por recomendación de los comentaristas.

```
<!-- Inicia espacio de declaraciones y Funciones Javascript -->

<script>


function archivos(form, fechaIni, fechaFin, fechaVigencia, definitivo, action){

    if(validaFechas()){

    var form          = document.getElementById(form);
    var fechaIniVal   = document.getElementById(fechaIni).value;
    var fechaFinVal   = document.getElementById(fechaFin).value;
    var fechaVigencia = document.getElementById(fechaVigencia).value;
    var definitivoVal = document.getElementById(definitivo).value;

    form.fhInicial.value        = fechaIniVal;
    form.fhFinal.value          = fechaFinVal;
    form.fhVigencia.value       = fechaVigencia;
    form.TipDefinitivoIn.value  = definitivoVal; 

    form.action     = action;
    form.target     ='_blank';
    form.method     ='POST';
    validNavigation = true;
    form.submit();
    form.target     ='_self'
    validNavigation = false;
    }else{
        $('#myModal').modal('hide');    
    }
```

}

```
function asignaValorChk(){

    if ($("#TipDefinitivo").is(':checked')){
        $("#TipDefinitivoIn").val(1);
     } else{
        $("#TipDefinitivoIn").val(0);
    };
  }

function validaFechas(){
    var error=0;
    var errorDes ="";
    var fhIni = $("#fhInicial").val();
    var fhFin = $("#fhFinal").val();
    var fhVig = $("#fhVigencia");

    if(validarFechaMenor(fhIni,fhFin)){
        error= error + 1;
        errorDes = errorDes + "¡Fecha inicio no puede ser mayor que Fecha Fin!"
    }
    if(error>0){
        muestraAlerta(3,errorDes);
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }

}

function validarFechaMenor(fhIni,fhFin)
{
      fechaInicio = fhIni.split("/");
      fechaFin    = fhFin.split("/");

 if(fechaInicio[2]>fechaFin[2]){
     return true;
 }     
 if((fechaInicio[2]==fechaFin[2])&&(fechaInicio[1]>fechaFin[1])){
     return true;
 }
 if((fechaInicio[2]==fechaFin[2])&&(fechaInicio[1] == fechaFin[1])&&(fechaInicio[0]>fechaFin[0])){
     return true;
 }
 return false;
}

function limpiarCampo(){
    $("#date-picker-input2").val('');
}
```

<%@include file="../menu1.jspf"%>
    <%@include file="../menu2.jspf"%>

```
            <h2> Reportes RTA.</h2>
            <form name="RtaForm" id="RtaForm" action="" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">  


                Fecha Inicio:
                    <div class="input-append datepicker date" data-date="" data-date-format="mm-dd-yyyy">
                      <input class="span6" size="20" type="text" value="" id="date-picker-input" rel="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Selección de Fecha Inicio" readonly />
                      <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
                    <input type = "hidden" name="fhInicial" id="fhInicial"/>
                    </div>

                Fecha Fin:
                     <div class="input-append datepicker date" data-date="" data-date-format="mm-dd-yyyy">
                      <input class="span6" size="20" type="text" value="" id="date-picker-input1" rel="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Selección de Fecha Fin" readonly/>
                      <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
                    <input type = "hidden" name="fhFinal" id="fhFinal"/>
                    </div>

                Fecha Vigencia:
                     <div class="input-append datepicker date" data-date="" data-date-format="mm-dd-yyyy">
                      <input class="span6" size="20" type="text" value="" id="date-picker-input2" rel="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Selección de Fecha Vigencia" readonly/>
                      <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" id="limpia-campo" onclick="limpiarCampo();">Limpiar</button>
                    <input type = "hidden" name="fhVigencia" id="fhVigencia" />
                    </div>    
                    <br><br>

                <div class="span6">
                    <label class="container"> En firme:
                        <input type="checkbox" value="Option one" name="TipDefinitivo" id="TipDefinitivo" onclick="asignaValorChk();">
                        <span class="checkmark"></span>
                    </label> 
                        <input type ="hidden" name="TipDefinitivoIn" id="TipDefinitivoIn" value = "0"/>
                </div>
                    <br><br>

                    <div class="span6">
                    <a href="#" id='generaboton'  role="button" class="btn btn-primary" title="Genera archivo" onclick="archivos('RtaForm','date-picker-input','date-picker-input1','date-picker-input2','TipDefinitivoIn','ReporteRtaAnterior');"><i class=""></i> Generar Reporte RTA </a><br>
                    </div>
                    </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Utilizo Boostrap versión 2.3.0 y jQuery 1.9.1

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Saludos, podrias agregar tu codigo JS para poder darte una mejor solución

Comment: Te recomiendo leer [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), a tu pregunta le falta información como la versión de Bootstrap, ¿qué es DatePicker? ¿el Widget de jQuery UI?

Comment: si dices que los 3 se cargan automaticamente, si recuerdo bien, el datapicker se maneja por el id, **id="date-picker-input2"**. Cambiando el id del input de la vigencia debería bastar. saludos

Comment: - No afecto la carga de la fecha usando JS, por lo que no es problema de ese código.

Comment: también podrías poner el código completo de tu problema, para analizar bien donde esta el error

Comment: Ya probé cambiando los id's, pero no tuvo efecto.  Al parecer es tema del class en el input .. el input-append, datepicker y date son los que me hacen ese efecto .. pero no puedo prescindir de ellos.

Comment: a sugerencia de ello.. agrego el código completo.. Muchas gracias por su atención.

Comment: en tu función limpiarCampo prueba con **$("#date-picker-input2").empty()**

Comment: mi solución temporal es agregar el boton de "Limpiar" .. y asignar vacio al campo ... pero sigo buscando la manera de eliminar ese botón y que quede libre el campo para ingresar la fecha o no